# jquery stop sliding delay if button is pressed more than once

Tags: jquery, slider

I know there is a way to stop the code from looping everytime you call an animation in jquery but for the life of me i can not find it!

How can i turn this code below in order for it not to keep looping if i push the button more than one?

```
$('#message-box').slideDown('slow').delay(10000).slideUp('slow');
```

If i hit the button that calls that more than once then it slides down, displays for 10 secs, slides back up then back down again.

What i would like it to do is if its already down and i hit the button then **NOT** to display it again. Or if nothing else, slide up the current message and slide down the new one right then and there without the delay between.

Any help would be great!

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$('#message-box').stop(true,true).slideDown('slow').delay(10000).slideUp('slow');
```

If there is a down-delay-up animation already in progress for the element then `.stop(true)` will stop that, clear the element's animation queue, and only then requeue the down-delay-up thing.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bSeE7/

Comment: I am calling the message box from code so if they get it incorrect then it drops down but once they have it correct will it display "correct" msgbox since its stopped?

Comment: Note: Using .stop(true,true) causes the slide animation to 'jumptoend' causing jerky animation.

Comment: @alpacalips - Yeah, I know, but without the "jumptoend" behaviour it can get a bit confused and get stuck halfway even on later slides. I think Clint's answer with the `:animated` selector is the best option.

Answer (score 2):

This will check to see if the message element is already being animated before running the function.

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
    if (!$('#message-box').is(':animated')) {
        $('#message-box').slideDown('slow').delay(10000).slideUp('slow')
    }
});
​
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest method if you only want event to occur once is one()

http://api.jquery.com/one/

```
$('#myButton').one('click', function(){
    $('#message-box').slideDown('slow').delay(10000).slideUp('slow');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

check out " .one "

http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#message-box').slideDown('slow', function(){
$('#message-box').delay(10000).slideUp('slow');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a conditional to prevent it from being activated when it's running. The callback function will reset the boolean to allow you to then click on it again when the animation is finished.

```
var animationRunning = false;

if(!animationRunning) {
    $('#message-box').slideDown('slow')
                     .delay(10000)
                     .slideUp('slow', function() { animationRunning = false; });

    animationRunning = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using .stop() is the obvious answer but when used with .slideUp() a small fraction of height is still displayed whenever .stop() is invoked. You could use [.stop(true,true)](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) but that will cause the slide animation to 'jumptoend' causing jerky animation. Not ideal.

Consider using `.animate()` instead of .slideUp()

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alpacalips/fQfv8/1/)

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('#message-box').stop(true).animate({height: 100}).delay(1000).animate({height: 0});
});
```